# When two identical fermions exchange, the wavefunction changes sign. Then why the statement is no new state is created?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

When two identical fermions exchange, the wavefunction changes sign. Then why the statement is no new state is created now that the wavefunction is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in quantum mechanics we're always interested in the probability, so it's not so important $\psi$ as much as $|\psi|^2$. By this you'll see that a change in sign does not change the probability density. Moreover not only a change in sing but a global phase won't change the state

$$ e^{i\phi}\psi \implies |e^{i\phi}\psi|^2 = |\psi|^2 $$ since $|e^{i\phi}|^2 = 1$. A change of sign it's just a specific case of a global phase since, putting $\phi=\pi$ you'll get $e^{i\pi} = -1$.

This fact is deeply rooted in the axioms of quantum mechanics, namely

> Each physical system is associated with a separable complex Hilber space for which quantum states are **rays** in it. A ray is just an equivalence class on the Hilbert space, where the equivalence is, given two elements  $\psi, \psi^\prime\in H$ $$\psi^\prime\sim\psi\qquad\text{when }\psi^\prime = e^{i\phi}\psi $$

All of this is just because, I want to stress it, in quantum mechanics the only physically relevent quantities are the probability density and not the wavefunctions in itself.